# Pandas fill in missing date within each group with information in the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group), but with some modifications:

Instead of filling in missing dates for each group between the min and max date of the entire column, we only should be filling in the dates between the min and the max of *that group*, and output a dataframe with the last row in each group

Reproducible example:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'dt': ['2016-01-01','2016-01-03', '2016-01-04','2016-01-01','2016-01-01','2016-01-04']
                    ,'amount': [10.0,30.0,40.0,78.0,80.0,82.0]
                    , 'sub_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2]
                    })
```

Visually:

```
            dt   sub_id   amount
0   2016-01-01        1     10.0
1   2016-01-03        1     30.0
2   2016-01-04        1     40.0
3   2017-01-01        2     78.0
4   2017-01-01        2     80.0
5   2017-01-04        2     82.0
```

Output I need:

```
            dt   sub_id   amount
0   2016-01-01        1     10.0
1   2016-01-02        1     10.0
2   2016-01-03        1     30.0
3   2016-01-04        1     40.0
4   2017-01-01        2     80.0
5   2017-01-02        2     80.0
6   2017-01-03        2     80.0
7   2017-01-04        2     82.0
```

We are grouping by dt and sub_id. As you can see, in sub_id=1, a row was added for 2016-01-02 and amount was imputed at 10.0 as the previous row was 10.0 (Assume data is sorted beforehand to enable this). For sub_id=2 row was added for 2017-01-02 and 2017-01-03 and amount is 80.0 as that was the last row before this date. The first row for 2017-01-01 was also deleted because we just want to keep the last row for each date and sub_id.

Looking for the most efficient way to do this as the real data has millions of rows. I have a current method using lambda functions and applying them across groups of sub_id but I feel like we could do better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the date right of course:

```
x.dt = pd.to_datetime(x.dt)
```

Then this:

```
cols = ['dt', 'sub_id']

pd.concat([
    d.asfreq('D').ffill(downcast='infer')
    for _, d in x.drop_duplicates(cols, keep='last')
                 .set_index('dt').groupby('sub_id')
]).reset_index()

          dt  amount  sub_id
0 2016-01-01      10       1
1 2016-01-02      10       1
2 2016-01-03      30       1
3 2016-01-04      40       1
4 2016-01-01      80       2
5 2016-01-02      80       2
6 2016-01-03      80       2
7 2016-01-04      82       2
```

Comment: note this answer requires the data to be sorted by date to start!

Answer (score 4):

By using `resample` with `groupby`

```
x.dt=pd.to_datetime(x.dt)
x.set_index('dt').groupby('sub_id').apply(lambda x : x.resample('D').max().ffill()).reset_index(level=1)
Out[265]: 
               dt  amount  sub_id
sub_id                           
1      2016-01-01    10.0     1.0
1      2016-01-02    10.0     1.0
1      2016-01-03    30.0     1.0
1      2016-01-04    40.0     1.0
2      2016-01-01    80.0     2.0
2      2016-01-02    80.0     2.0
2      2016-01-03    80.0     2.0
2      2016-01-04    82.0     2.0
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is very clean but I had a similar solution and because it uses apply, performance is quite slow. piRSquared' s solution worked best for me

Comment: I take above comment back. The performance difference between this and other solutions is due to the resample('D').max() step. Using drop duplicates first and then doing asfreq('D') is much faster

Answer (score 2):

use `asfreq` & `groupby`

first convert `dt` to `datetime` & get rid of duplicates

then for each group of `sub_id` use `asfreq('D', method='ffill')` to generate missing dates and impute amounts

finally `reset_index` on `amount` column as there's a duplicate `sub_id` column as well as index.

```
x.dt = pd.to_datetime(x.dt)
x.drop_duplicates(
  ['dt', 'sub_id'], 'last'
).groupby('sub_id').apply(
  lambda x: x.set_index('dt').asfreq('D', method='ffill')
).amount.reset_index()

# output:

   sub_id         dt  amount
0       1 2016-01-01    10.0
1       1 2016-01-02    10.0
2       1 2016-01-03    30.0
3       1 2016-01-04    40.0
4       2 2016-01-01    80.0
5       2 2016-01-02    80.0
6       2 2016-01-03    80.0
7       2 2016-01-04    82.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me and seems pretty efficient, but I can't say if it's efficient enough. It does avoid lambdas tho.

I called your data `df`.

Create a `base_df` with the entire date / sub_id grid:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

base_grid = product(pd.date_range(df['dt'].min(), df['dt'].max(), freq='D'), list(range(df['sub_id'].min(), df['sub_id'].max() + 1, 1)))

base_df = pd.DataFrame(list(base_grid), columns=['dt', 'sub_id'])
```

Get the max value per dt / sub_id from `df`:

```
max_value_df = df.loc[df.groupby(['dt', 'sub_id'])['amount'].idxmax()]
max_value_df['dt']  = max_value_df['dt'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Merge base_df on the max values:

```
merged_df = base_df.merge(max_value_df, how='left', on=['dt', 'sub_id'])
```

Sort and forward fill the maximal value:

```
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(by=['sub_id', 'dt', 'amount'], ascending=True)
merged_df['amount'] = merged_df.groupby(['sub_id'])['amount'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Result:

```
    dt  sub_id  amount
0   2016-01-01  1   10.0
2   2016-01-02  1   10.0
4   2016-01-03  1   30.0
6   2016-01-04  1   40.0
1   2016-01-01  2   80.0
3   2016-01-02  2   80.0
5   2016-01-03  2   80.0
7   2016-01-04  2   82.0
```