# Pandas fill-in-zero for by missing dates *defined by* group

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby, missing-data

Question: Using pandas -- how to efficiently fill-in missing dates with zero values, with monthly (e.g. last day indexed) frequency, relative to the min/max date values *per* group?

*Edit* do not assume input dates to correspond to the last day in its month.
To deal with this issue, add the following line to the proposed answers below:

```
df.date = df.date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

*Without this fix, filled in values with freq='M' can results in NA's...!*

Note:
pandas version 0.24.2

Example input:

```
data = [{'name': 'A', 'date': '2019-01-01', 'val': 10},
{'name': 'A', 'date': '2019-04-30', 'val': 2},
{'name': 'B', 'date': '2019-02-15', 'val': 6},
{'name': 'B', 'date': '2019-05-01', 'val': 5}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         date name  val
0  2019-01-01    A   10
1  2019-04-30    A    2
2  2019-02-15    B    6
3  2019-05-01    B    5
```

Note that the dates in the input are not necessarily the first or last day of their corresponding month.

Example desired output

```
         date name  val
0  2019-01-31    A   10
1  2019-02-28    A    0
2  2019-03-31    A    0
3  2019-04-30    A    2
4  2019-02-28    B    6
5  2019-03-31    B    0
6  2019-04-30    B    0
7  2019-05-31    B    5
```

Attempts:

The following works at the index level but fills everything with NA:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

dg = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(min(x.date), max(x.date), freq='M')))
```

Also:

[Pandas filling missing dates and values within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group/44979696#44979696)

The above link's answer appear not be not relative to for each group, but rather the entire dataset's min/max date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `groupby`, `resample` and `asfreq` (*edit: as you updated the question on non-MonthEnd dates. I added `pd.offsets.MonthEnd` as you proposed*)

```
df.date = df.date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) 
(df.set_index('date').groupby('name').resample('M')
                     .asfreq(fill_value=0).drop('name',1)
                     .reset_index())

Out[550]:
  name       date  val
0    A 2019-01-31   10
1    A 2019-02-28    0
2    A 2019-03-31    0
3    A 2019-04-30    2
4    B 2019-02-28    6
5    B 2019-03-31    0
6    B 2019-04-30    0
7    B 2019-05-31    5
```

Comment: to play safe with "resample('M')", add the following line: df.date = df.date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: ah, I see your point. You want to handle anomoly cases where some values in `df.date` is not month-end date :)

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl: I added `pd.offsets.MonthEnd` as you proposed to make the answer completed :)

Comment: @AndyL.: How would you add same range of dates for each group? I mean each group has same range (ie, 2020 Jan to 2020 Dec). How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

new_df = (df.set_index('date')
            .groupby('name', as_index=False)
            .apply(lambda x: x.resample('M').interpolate())
            .reset_index(0, drop=True)
         )

s = new_df['name'].isna() 
new_df.loc[s, 'val'] = 0
new_df['name'] = new_df['name'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
           name   val
date                 
2019-01-31    A  10.0
2019-02-28    A   0.0
2019-03-31    A   0.0
2019-04-30    A   2.0
2019-02-28    B   6.0
2019-03-31    B   0.0
2019-04-30    B   0.0
2019-05-31    B   5.0
```

Comment: it seems that using "interpolate" will sometimes (on large datasets) result in the final output having all NA's -- changing your "interpolate" to "max" seems to solve this problem.

Comment: to play safe with "resample('M')", add the following line: df.date = df.date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)