# tricky python pandas conditional math with a lot of missing rows in different columns and possible reindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reindex

Imaging there is a dataframe with a lot of missing transaction_total and balance_total and date

```
id,date,transaction_total,balance_total
1,01/01/2019,-1,102
1,01/02/2019,-2,100
1,01/03/2019,-3,
1,01/04/2019,,
1,01/05/2019,-4,
2,01/01/2019,-2,200
2,01/02/2019,-2,100
2,01/04/2019,,
2,01/05/2019,-4,
```

Here is the create-input script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

users=pd.DataFrame(
                [
                {'id':1,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-1, 'balance_total':102},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/03/2019', 'transaction_total':-3, 'balance_total':''},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':'', 'balance_total':''},
                {'id':1,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':''},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/01/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':200},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/02/2019', 'transaction_total':-2, 'balance_total':100},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/04/2019', 'transaction_total':'', 'balance_total':''},
                {'id':2,'date':'01/05/2019', 'transaction_total':-4, 'balance_total':''}  
                ]
                )
```

the goal is to achieve the following:

desired FINAL output:

```
id,date,balance_total
1,01/01/2019,102
1,01/02/2019,100
1,01/03/2019,97
1,01/04/2019,97
1,01/05/2019,93
2,01/01/2019,200
2,01/02/2019,100
2,01/03/2019,97
2,01/04/2019,97
2,01/05/2019,93
```

(1) if the date is missing, fill the date with the balance from the previous date (i think the reindex solution in this link might work [Pandas filling missing dates and values within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group) )

(2)if the balance_total is missing while there are valid 'date' and 'transaction_total', fill the "balance total" with "the previous date's balance_total-the transaction_total on the date when the balance_total is missing" (the case in row 3: 100+ (-3)=97)

(3) if there is a valid date, but both of the transaction_total and balance_total are NaN, just fill in the last date's balance_total (e.g. row 4: since the total_balance in 01/03/2019 will be 97 based on the previous calculation, the 01/04/2019 balance will be 97 because there is no transaction_total.)

desired metadata output:

```
id,date,transaction_total,balance_total
1,01/01/2019,-1,102
1,01/02/2019,-2,100
1,01/03/2019,-3,97
1,01/04/2019,0,97
1,01/05/2019,-4,93
2,01/01/2019,-2,200
2,01/02/2019,-2,100
2,01/03/2019,-3,97
2,01/04/2019,,97
2,01/05/2019,-4,93
```

Comment: How is the balance total in first row `98`?

Comment: typo. let me correct it. should be 102

Comment: just corrected it @Vishnudev I also provide the example data creation script!