# Fill missing dates with values from previous row per group with duplicated entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have the following dataframe (sample):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', '2022-09-01', 2], ['A', '2022-09-02', 1], ['A', '2022-09-04', 3], ['A', '2022-09-06', 2],
        ['A', '2022-09-07', 1], ['A', '2022-09-07', 2], ['A', '2022-09-08', 4], ['A', '2022-09-09', 2],
        ['B', '2022-09-01', 2], ['B', '2022-09-03', 4], ['B', '2022-09-04', 2], ['B', '2022-09-05', 2],
        ['B', '2022-09-07', 1], ['B', '2022-09-08', 3], ['B', '2022-09-10', 2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'date', 'value'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['diff_days'] = (df['date']-df['date'].groupby(df['group']).transform('first')).dt.days

   group       date  value  diff_days
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1
2      A 2022-09-04      3          3
3      A 2022-09-06      2          5
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6
5      A 2022-09-07      2          6
6      A 2022-09-08      4          7
7      A 2022-09-09      2          8
8      B 2022-09-01      2          0
9      B 2022-09-03      4          2
10     B 2022-09-04      2          3
11     B 2022-09-05      2          4
12     B 2022-09-07      1          6
13     B 2022-09-08      3          7
14     B 2022-09-10      2          9
```

I would like to fill in the missing dates with the values from the previous date per group. I could use the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219496/pandas-fill-missing-row-with-dates-and-value-from-previous-data), but the problem is that I could have duplicated entries (dates) per group. The following error returns:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.set_index(
    ['date', 'group']
).unstack(
    fill_value=-999
).asfreq(
    'D', fill_value=-999
).stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index()

df.replace(-999, np.nan).ffill()

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

My desired output should look like this:

```
data = [['A', '2022-09-01', 2, 0], ['A', '2022-09-02', 1, 1], ['A', '2022-09-03', 1, 1], ['A', '2022-09-04', 3, 3], 
        ['A', '2022-09-05', 3, 3], ['A', '2022-09-06', 2, 5], ['A', '2022-09-07', 1, 6], ['A', '2022-09-07', 2, 6], 
        ['A', '2022-09-08', 4, 7], ['A', '2022-09-09', 2, 8],
        ['B', '2022-09-01', 2, 0], ['B', '2022-09-02', 2, 0], ['B', '2022-09-03', 4, 2], ['B', '2022-09-04', 2, 3], 
        ['B', '2022-09-05', 2, 4], ['B', '2022-09-06', 2, 4], ['B', '2022-09-07', 1, 6], ['B', '2022-09-08', 3, 7], 
        ['B', '2022-09-09', 3, 7], ['B', '2022-09-10', 2, 9]]
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['group', 'date', 'value', ' diff_days'])

   group        date  value   diff_days
0      A  2022-09-01      2           0
1      A  2022-09-02      1           1
2      A  2022-09-03      1           1
3      A  2022-09-04      3           3
4      A  2022-09-05      3           3
5      A  2022-09-06      2           5
6      A  2022-09-07      1           6
7      A  2022-09-07      2           6
8      A  2022-09-08      4           7
9      A  2022-09-09      2           8
10     B  2022-09-01      2           0
11     B  2022-09-02      2           0
12     B  2022-09-03      4           2
13     B  2022-09-04      2           3
14     B  2022-09-05      2           4
15     B  2022-09-06      2           4
16     B  2022-09-07      1           6
17     B  2022-09-08      3           7
18     B  2022-09-09      3           7
19     B  2022-09-10      2           9
```

Some dates explained:

- For group A the dates "2022-09-03" and "2022-09-05" are missing. As you can see these get the values from the previous date.
- For group B the dates "2022-09-02", "2022-09-06" and "2022-09-09" are missing. Also for these, they get the values from the previous row.

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fill these missing dates even when there could be duplicated entries per group using `Pandas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Solution

```
c = ['group', 'date']
m = df[c].duplicated(keep='last')

s = df[~m].set_index('date').groupby('group').resample('D').ffill()
out = pd.concat([df[m], s.droplevel(0).reset_index()]).sort_values(c)
```

##### How this works?

- Identify the duplicate rows per `group` and `date`
- Remove the dupes and `resample` the dataframe with *forward fill*
- `Concat` the duplicate rows with the resampled rows to get the result

Result

```
   group       date  value  diff_days
0      A 2022-09-01      2          0
1      A 2022-09-02      1          1
2      A 2022-09-03      1          1
3      A 2022-09-04      3          3
4      A 2022-09-05      3          3
5      A 2022-09-06      2          5
4      A 2022-09-07      1          6
6      A 2022-09-07      2          6
7      A 2022-09-08      4          7
8      A 2022-09-09      2          8
9      B 2022-09-01      2          0
10     B 2022-09-02      2          0
11     B 2022-09-03      4          2
12     B 2022-09-04      2          3
13     B 2022-09-05      2          4
14     B 2022-09-06      2          4
15     B 2022-09-07      1          6
16     B 2022-09-08      3          7
17     B 2022-09-09      3          7
18     B 2022-09-10      2          9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deduplicate the date with a helper column:

```
(df.assign(n=df.groupby(['group', 'date']).cumcount())
   .pivot(index=['date', 'n'], columns='group')
   .ffill()
   .stack().reset_index()
   .sort_values(by=['group', 'date'], ignore_index=True)
   [df.columns]
)
```

output:

```
   group       date  value  diff_days
0      A 2022-09-01    2.0        0.0
1      A 2022-09-02    1.0        1.0
2      A 2022-09-03    1.0        1.0
3      A 2022-09-04    3.0        3.0
4      A 2022-09-05    3.0        3.0
5      A 2022-09-06    2.0        5.0
6      A 2022-09-07    1.0        6.0
7      A 2022-09-07    2.0        6.0
8      A 2022-09-08    4.0        7.0
9      A 2022-09-09    2.0        8.0
10     A 2022-09-10    2.0        8.0
11     B 2022-09-01    2.0        0.0
12     B 2022-09-02    2.0        0.0
13     B 2022-09-03    4.0        2.0
14     B 2022-09-04    2.0        3.0
15     B 2022-09-05    2.0        4.0
16     B 2022-09-06    2.0        4.0
17     B 2022-09-07    1.0        6.0
18     B 2022-09-07    1.0        6.0
19     B 2022-09-08    3.0        7.0
20     B 2022-09-09    3.0        7.0
21     B 2022-09-10    2.0        9.0
```