# Adding all Missing date range to Data Frame using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to the python. What is my ask is? I have a data frame describing employees of some company. Each employee have unique employee id. The data frame shows monthly record of the number of hours for all employees. So there might be some days missing from DF for each employee. So those date range have to filled as zero rows with column date as missing date and Id as employee id.
Example -

```
Employee WH       Date    othercol1 othercol2 othercol3 
11        6  2021-06-03 
11        7  2021-06-06
11        8  2021-06-08
13        5  2021-06-01
13        7  2021-06-02
13        7  2021-06-28
```

The missing date for employee id 11 is `01,02,04,05,07,09---30`
The missing date for employee id 13 is `03,--27, 29,30`. Like so there can be multiple employee with missing date range.
The dataframe need to filled with all those missing values and reindexed. Please help.

Comment: Can there be multiple months for each ID or just one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas filling missing dates and values within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group)

Comment: There will be only one month. Also as it is monthly data so all ID's will going t have same month.

Comment: See the second answer at the link I posted above: `df.set_index(['Date', 'Employee']).unstack(fill_value=0).asfreq('D', fill_value=0).stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index()`

Comment: Ask is to find missing date for every group and insert Zero values with date and id for those groups.

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes I did. I am looking for complete month.