# Add missing dates to pandas dataframe for different group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, missing-data

My data time-series for different stocks where it will be big dataset. What I need is to fill missing date from 2012-01 to 2012-12 for all stocks with value 0 for other columns.

Here is the data sample

```
    stock = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
    ym = ['2012-01','2012-02','2012-04','2012-05','2012-10','2012-02','2012-04','2012-05','2012-01','2012-12']
    V1 = [0.345, 0.456, 0.456, 0, 0, 0.123, 0, 0.987, 0.765, 0.853]
    V2 = [0.245, 0.356, 0.156, 0, 0, 0.023, 0, 0.787, 0.565, 0.353]
    
    list_of_tuples = list(zip(stock, ym, V1, V2))
    test = pd.DataFrame(list_of_tuples,
                columns=["stock", "ym", "V1", "V2"])

    out:
       stock       ym     V1     V2
    0      1  2012-01  0.345  0.245
    1      1  2012-02  0.456  0.356
    2      1  2012-04  0.456  0.156
    3      1  2012-05  0.000  0.000
    4      1  2012-10  0.000  0.000
    5      2  2012-02  0.123  0.023
    6      2  2012-04  0.000  0.000
    7      2  2012-05  0.987  0.787
    8      3  2012-01  0.765  0.565
    9      3  2012-12  0.853  0.353
```

I have tried the method suggested by this [Pandas filling missing dates and values within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group) where I get this error

```
    ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

I think that the error is coming from the duplicate date eg.2012-02 for stock 1 and 2. But I need all date to all stocks.

My expected result would be

```
    out:
        stock       ym     V1     V2
    0       1  2012-01  0.345  0.245
    1       1  2012-02  0.456  0.356
    2       1  2012-03  0.000  0.000
    3       1  2012-04  0.456  0.156
    4       1  2012-05  0.000  0.000
    5       1  2012-06  0.000  0.000
    6       1  2012-07  0.000  0.000
    7       1  2012-08  0.000  0.000
    8       1  2012-09  0.000  0.000
    9       1  2012-10  0.000  0.000
    10      1  2012-11  0.000  0.000
    11      1  2012-12  0.000  0.000
    12      2  2012-01  0.000  0.000
    13      2  2012-02  0.123  0.023
    14      2  2012-03  0.000  0.000
    15      2  2012-04  0.000  0.000
    16      2  2012-05  0.987  0.787
    17      2  2012-06  0.000  0.000
    18      2  2012-07  0.000  0.000
    19      2  2012-08  0.000  0.000
    20      2  2012-09  0.000  0.000
    21      2  2012-10  0.000  0.000
    22      2  2012-11  0.000  0.000
    23      2  2012-12  0.000  0.000
    24      3  2012-01  0.765  0.565
    25      3  2012-02  0.000  0.000
    26      3  2012-03  0.000  0.000
    27      3  2012-04  0.000  0.000
    28      3  2012-05  0.000  0.000
    29      3  2012-06  0.000  0.000
    30      3  2012-07  0.000  0.000
    31      3  2012-08  0.000  0.000
    32      3  2012-09  0.000  0.000
    33      3  2012-10  0.000  0.000
    34      3  2012-11  0.000  0.000
    35      3  2012-12  0.853  0.353
```

Please help and thank you so much in advance.