# Filling missing dates and values for several groups - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    province    date        D I R C
360 Incheon     2020-01-20  0 0 1 1
455 Seoul       2020-01-23  0 0 1 1
183 Gyeonggi-do 2020-01-26  0 0 1 1
184 Gyeonggi-do 2020-01-27  0 0 2 2
456 Seoul       2020-01-30  0 0 4 4
```

And I need that, for every subsequent day after the first one (2020-01-20 in this case), I have the "last seen row" for each province, in case there are no updates in that date. So in the case of my example, I would want as a resulting df:

```
    province    date        D I R C
1   Incheon     2020-01-20  0 0 1 1

2   Incheon     2020-01-23  0 0 1 1
3   Seoul       2020-01-23  0 0 1 1

4   Gyeonggi-do 2020-01-26  0 0 1 1
5   Incheon     2020-01-26  0 0 1 1
6   Seoul       2020-01-26  0 0 1 1

7   Gyeonggi-do 2020-01-27  0 0 2 2
8   Incheon     2020-01-27  0 0 1 1
9   Seoul       2020-01-27  0 0 1 1

10  Seoul       2020-01-30  0 0 4 4
11  Gyeonggi-do 2020-01-30  0 0 2 2
12  Incheon     2020-01-30  0 0 1 1
```

Have tried what can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241795/fill-missing-dates-by-group-in-pandas), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe), but it is slightly different. My goal is to make a bar plot with time using plotly, which I can right now, but for every date that a province does not have any updates, i.e., no data, the bar disappears, and I need it to stay.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `set_index` and `reindex` with a `MultiiIndex.from_product` from all combinations of `unique` province and date, then `groupby` the province and `ffill`, `dropna` to remove the dates before the first occurrence of each province, `sort_index` per date (if necessary) and `reset_index` like:

```
(df.set_index(['province', 'date'])
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['province'].unique(), df['date'].unique()], 
                                       names=['province', 'date']))
   .groupby(level='province').ffill()
   .dropna()
   .sort_index(level='date')
   .reset_index()
)
       province        date    D    I    R    C
0       Incheon  2020-01-20  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1       Incheon  2020-01-23  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
2         Seoul  2020-01-23  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3   Gyeonggi-do  2020-01-26  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
4       Incheon  2020-01-26  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
5         Seoul  2020-01-26  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
6   Gyeonggi-do  2020-01-27  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0
7       Incheon  2020-01-27  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
8         Seoul  2020-01-27  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
9   Gyeonggi-do  2020-01-30  0.0  0.0  2.0  2.0
10      Incheon  2020-01-30  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
11        Seoul  2020-01-30  0.0  0.0  4.0  4.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, I get a warning "cannot insert province, already exists". Even if I drop the attribute `province` before resetting the index in the last step (fixing the warning), the resulting df here is not the expected, with wrong values in many places